# Optimizing Jquery Twitch TV Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I'm trying to get in the habit of writing better looking code and more efficient code blocks. I wrote this Twitch TV Application which allows you to add and edit channels and it lets you know when a channel is live. Is there anything I can work on to make my code work / look better?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Streaming</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="streamer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dynamic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="mainNav">
                <li id="streamInfo"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="chatAnchor">
                <li>
                    <a onclick="$(this).addClass('activeChat');$('#streamChat').removeClass('activeChat')" href="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?popout_chat=true&amp;channel=mxgdichello" target="chatFrame" id="mainChat" class="activeChat">
                        Main Chat
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tab" id="streamChat" onclick="changeChat()">
                        Stream Chat
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="player">
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="twitchTV" width="780px" 
            height="500px"></object>
        </div>
        <div id="chat">
            <iframe name="chatFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chatFrame" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?popout_chat=true&amp;channel=mxgdichello"></iframe>
        </div> 
        <div id="chanControls">
            <div id="add">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <img src="add.jpg" />
                </a>
                <form id="addChan" onSubmit="return addChannel()">
                    Streamer Name: 
                        <input type="text" name="title" />
                    Streamer Channel:
                        <span style="color:#383838; font-style:italic">
                            http://www.twitch.tv/
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" name="url" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Verify Channel" />
                    <span class="successMsg"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="edit">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <img src="edit.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="list">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery**

```
var streams = new Array();
var current = -1; // For viewers update
var twitch = false;
var youtube = false;
var timer = 60000; // Miliseconds
var toggleEdit = [editList, addList];
var toggleCounter = 0;         
var youtubePlayer = '<iframe width="765" height="500" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="youtubePlayer"></iframe>';
var twitchPlayer = '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="twitchTV" width="780px" height="500px"></object>';
var tubes = ["zn7-fVtT16k", "IVJVCoHDAXs", "1_hKLfTKU5Y", "l3w2MTXBebg", "UcTLJ692F70", "zj2Zf9tlg2Y", "mgVwv0ZuPhM",
            "7ZsKqbt3gQ0", "YHRxv-40WMU", "ZIMoQHpvFQQ", "TAaE7sJahiw", "xBzoBgfm55w", "AeNYDwbm9qw", "mhTd4_Ids80",
            "AFA-rOls8YA", "CeLrlmV9A-s", "7rE0-ek6MZA", "WA4tLCGcTG4", "0M0RbaPxq2k", "vICX-6dMOuA", "njos57IJf-0",
            "K5a_v0MP_Fk", "dX_1B0w7Hzc", "xDj7gvc_dsA", "17CLlZuiBkQ", "0kRAKXFrYQ4", "gJ1Mz7kGVf0", "-6G6CZT7h4",
            "liLU2tEz7KY", "eHCyaJS4Cbs", "uEIPCOwY4DE", "V2XGp5ix8HE", "DrQRS40OKNE", "BBcYG_J3O2Q", "upxzaVMhw8k",
            "0XcN12uVHeQ", "itvJybdcYbI", "l7iVsdRbhnc", "51V1VMkuyx0", "aQQeg3jYgOA", "XGK84Poeynk", "MaCZN2N6Q_I",
            "9q5pZ49r9aU", "DFM140rju4k", "qHBVnMf2t7w", "YtO-6Xg3g2M"];
var updateTimer = setInterval(getList, timer);          // Update the streams list every minute

$(window).load(function(){
    if(localStorage.length == 0)
    {
        var streamer1 = new Streamer("Gaurdsman Bob", "guardsmanbob", null, null);
        var streamer2 = new Streamer("Siv HD", "sivhd", null, null);
        var streamer3 = new Streamer("Day9 TV", "day9tv", null, null);
        localStorage.setItem(streamer1.url, JSON.stringify(streamer1));
        localStorage.setItem(streamer2.url, JSON.stringify(streamer2));
        localStorage.setItem(streamer3.url, JSON.stringify(streamer3));
    }

    getStorage();
    getList();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add a').click(function() {
        var lefty = $(this).next();
        lefty.animate({
          left: parseInt(lefty.css('left'),10) == 150 ?
            -lefty.width() : 150 
        });
    });

    $('#addChan input[name=title]').click(function(){
        var title = $('#addChan input[name=title]');
        if(title.val() == "Enter Streamer Name")
        {
            title.val('');
            title.css("border-color", "");
        }
    });

    $('#addChan input[name=url]').click(function(){
        var url = $('#addChan input[name=url]');
        if(url.val() == "Enter Streamer URL")
        {
            url.val('');
            url.css("border-color", "");
        }
    });

    $('#edit a').click(function(){
        if(toggleCounter % 2 == 1)
        {
            $(document).off('click', '#list li img');
            $(document).off('focusout', '#list input.editTitle');
        }

        toggleEdit[toggleCounter++%2]();
    });
});

function getList(){
    $.post(
        "streams.php",
        {streams : JSON.stringify(streams)}, 
        function(data) 
        {
            streams = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(streams, function(index, obj){ 
                $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                    if(current == -1 && value == 'online')
                    {
                        current = index;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

            if(current != -1 && !twitch)
                build(current);
            else if(current == -1 && !youtube)
                randomTube();

            if(twitch)
                updateViewers();
            addList();
        }
      );
}

function build(index){
    var data = 'http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=';   // Object Data
    var src = 'hostname=www.twitch.tv&auto_play=false&start_volume=25&channel='; // Flashvars Param
    var changeVars = '<param name="flashvars" \
    value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&auto_play=false&start_volume=100&channel='+streams[index].url+'"/>';
    var params = '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />' +
                 '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />' +
                 '<param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />' +
                 '<param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />' +
                 changeVars;
    $("#player").html(twitchPlayer);
    $("#twitchTV").html(params);
    $("#twitchTV").attr("data", data);
    if(streams[index].status == 'online')
        $('#streamInfo').html("<span id=\"streamTitle\">Streamer: " + streams[index].title + 
            "</span> - <span id=\"viewers\">" + streams[index].viewers + "</span> Viewers");
    else
        $('#streamInfo').text("Streamer: " + streams[index].title + " - Offline");

    current = index;
    twitch = true;
}

function addList(){
    var numOffline = 0;
    var online = '';
    var offline = '';
    var curr = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == current && streams[i].status == 'online') 
        {
                curr = '<li class="item"><div class="online"></div><a style="color:green" href="javascript: void(0)" \
                        title="'+streams[i].title+' Stream" \
                        onClick="changeStream($(this).text())">'+streams[i].title+'</a></li>';
        }
        else if(streams[i].status == 'online' && i != current)
        {
                online += '<li class="item"><div class="online"></div><a style="color:green" href="javascript: void(0)" \
                        title="'+streams[i].title+' Stream" \
                        onClick="changeStream($(this).text())">'+streams[i].title+'</a></li>';
        }
        else
        {
            offline += '<li class="item"><div class="offline"></div><a href="javascript: void(0)" \
                       title="'+streams[i].title+' Stream - Offline" \
                       onClick="changeStream($(this).text())">'+streams[i].title+'</a></li>';
            numOffline++;
        }
    }

    if(numOffline == streams.length)
    {
        online += '<li class="item"><div class="online"></div><a style="color:green" href="javascript: void(0)" \
                        title="Random Youtube" onClick="randomTube()">Random Youtube</a></li>';
    }

    $('#list ul').html(curr + online + offline);
}

function editList(){
    clearInterval(updateTimer);
    var online = '';
    var offline = '';
    var curr = '';
    var previousText;

    for(var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == current && streams[i].status == 'online')
        {
            curr = '<li class="item"><div><img src="greenDelete.png" /></div> \
                        <input type="text" value="'+streams[i].title+'" class="editTitle" /></li>';
        }
        else if(streams[i].status == 'online' && i != curr)
        {
                online += '<li class="item"><div><img src="greenDelete.png" /></div>\
                            <input type="text" value="'+streams[i].title+'" class="editTitle" /></li>';
        }
        else
        {
            offline += '<li class="item"><div><img src="redDelete.png" /></div>\
                            <input type="text" value="'+streams[i].title+'" class="editTitle" /></li>';
        }
    }

    $('#list ul').html(curr + online + offline);

    $(document).on('click', '#list li div img', function(){
        var find = $(this).parent().next("input").val();
        alert(find);
        var index = findObjByTitle(streams, find);
        var obj =  streams.splice(index, 1);
        removeFromStorage(obj[0]);
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    $(document).on('focus', '#list input.editTitle', function(){
        previousText = this.value;
    });
    $(document).off('focus', '#list input.editTitle', function(){});

    $(document).on('focusout', '#list input.editTitle', function(){
        var index = findObjByTitle(streams, previousText);
        streams[index].title = this.value;
        updateStorage(streams[index]);
    });
}

function updateViewers(){
    if(typeof(streams[current]) != 'undefined')
        $('#viewers').text(streams[current].viewers);
}

function changeChat(){
    var chatSrc = $('#chatFrame').attr('src');
    var chat = chatSrc.split('channel=');
    $('#chatFrame').attr('src', chat[0]+'channel='+streams[current].url);
    $('#mainChat').removeClass('activeChat');
    $('#streamChat').addClass('activeChat');
}

function changeStream(find){
    var found = false
    $.each(streams, function(index, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            if(!found && streams[index].title == find)
            {
                build(index);
                current = index;
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    if($('#streamChat').hasClass('activeChat'))
        changeChat();
}

function randomTube(){
    var video = tubes[Math.floor(Math.random()*tubes.length)];
    $('#player').html(youtubePlayer);
    $('#player iframe').attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ video);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+video+"?v=2&alt=json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data){
            $('#streamInfo').html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" style="color:#ae0000" title="Random Video" onClick="randomTube()">\
                Random Video</a> -- ' + data.entry.title.$t);
        }
    });
    youtube = true;
}

function addChannel(){
    var tempStreamer;
    var title = $('#addChan input[name=title]');
    var url = $('#addChan input[name=url]');

    if(title.val() == '' && url.val() == '')
    {
        title.css("border-color", "red");
        title.val("Enter Streamer Name");
        url.css("border-color", "red");
        url.val("Enter Streamer URL");
        return false;
    }
    else if(title.val() == '')
    {
        title.css("border-color", "red");
        title.val("Enter Streamer Name");
        return false;
    }
    else if(url.val() == '')
    {
        url.css("border-color", "red");
        url.val("Enter Streamer URL");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        title = title.val();
        url = (url.serialize()).split('=');
    }
    tempStreamer = new Streamer(title, url[1], null, null);
    $.post(
        "chanExists.php",
        {streams : tempStreamer}, 
        function(data){
            tempStreamer = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(!(tempStreamer.status))
            {
                $('#addChan .successMsg').text("Channel Does Not Exist!");
                $('#addChan .successMsg').css('color', 'red');
            }
            else
            {
                var objIndex = objExists(streams, tempStreamer);

                if(objIndex == -1)
                {
                    $('#addChan .successMsg').text("Channel Added!");
                    $('#addChan .successMsg').css('color', 'green');
                    localStorage.setItem(tempStreamer.url, JSON.stringify(tempStreamer));
                    streams.push(tempStreamer);
                    clearInterval(updateTimer);
                    getList();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#addChan .successMsg').text("Channel " + streams[objIndex].title + " Already Added");
                    $('#addChan .successMsg').css('color', 'red');
                }
            }
    });
    updateTimer = setInterval(getList, timer);
    return false;
}

/*******************************
/*  The Following are Storage
/*  Manipulation Functions
*******************************/

function getStorage(){
    var tempStream;
    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
    {
        tempStream = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        streams.push(tempStream);
    }
}

function removeFromStorage(obj){
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; (i < localStorage.length && !found); i++)
    {
        tempStream = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        if(tempStream.url = obj.url)
        {
            localStorage.removeItem(obj.url);
            found = true;
        }
    }
}

function updateStorage(obj){
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; (i < localStorage.length && !found); i++)
    {
        tempStream = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        if(tempStream.url = obj.url)
        {
            localStorage.removeItem(obj.url);
            localStorage.setItem(obj.url, JSON.stringify(obj));
            found = true;
        }
    }
}

/*******************
/* Streamer Object
/* And Member Functions
*******************/

function Streamer(title, url, status, viewers)
{
    this.title=title;
    this.url=url;
    this.status=status;
    this.viewers=viewers;
}

function objExists(arr, obj)
{
    var i = arr.length;
    while(i--)
    {
        if(arr[i].url == obj.url)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function findObjByTitle(arr, title)
{
    var found = false;
    var i = 0;
    while(!found)
    {
        if(arr[i].title == title)
        {
            return i;
        }       
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- You are mixing single double quote and double quote strings, you should stick to 1
- It is considered better style to have a single comma separated `var` statement
- For

  ```
  $('#addChan input[name=title]').click(function(){
      var title = $('#addChan input[name=title]');
      if(title.val() == "Enter Streamer Name")
      {
          title.val('');
          title.css("border-color", "");
      }
  });
  ```

  - You could do `var $this = $(this)
  - You could chain `.val` and `.css` to `title.val('').css("border-color", "");`
  - You might be able to unify `$('#addChan input[name=title]').click(function(){` and `$('#addChan input[name=url]').click(function(){` they are pretty much the same
- Your `$.post` calls have no error handling at all, you should look at that
- `current` is a terrible name, current what ?
- `$.each(streams, function(index, obj){` -> `obj` should have been `stream`
- HTML building in general: consider a template function, either find a good library or build your own
- Your declaration of variables is not consistent, I can understand why you want to declare `twitchPlayer` on top, because it could get modified and you could consider the top part a 'config section'. But then you declare `changeVars` inside `build()`.. I think you need to re-think where to put which variables
- `addList` has total copy pastage, please consider using a helper function, or perhaps even a temporary variable to hold the `<li></li>` and then concatenate into the right string
- The same goes for `editList`
- In `addChannel` you re-purpose `title` and `url` from a jQuery object to a value, not good practice
- In `addChannel` you should not check for `if(title.val() == '' && url.val() == '')` as you are basically combining what you already coded for `else if(title.val() == '')` and `else if(url.val() == '')`
- `function getStorage(){` is funny and shows a general problem with the code. Instead of return what is in storage, as the name would let you believe, a global variable gets set. On the whole, your code is too reliant on globals
- In `updateStorage`, I dont believe you need to call `removeItem` first
- I would expect `objExists` to return a boolean, perhaps call it `objIndex` ?
- `findObjByTitle`

  - You never use `found`
  - You never return a boolean
  - It seems you could go infinite loop if the title is not at all in the array

I hope my feedback does not sound too harsh, it is still an impressive piece of code. You have extracted a lot of constants into well named variables, your functionality is well split over functions. I think you could just use a few more rounds of polishing.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - Year too late xD - it was a nice stepping stone project and you're right, much of it is redundant and how I handled the ajax call was always sloppy. Not sure what exactly classifies as a answer here but none-the-less I appreciate the input :D !